# Increase allowed size of SDA - Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, server

I'm on Ubuntu Server.
Here is the result of 'df -m'

```
Filesystem     1M-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3           9046  7540      1047  88% /
udev                1966     1      1966   1% /dev
tmpfs                395     1       395   1% /run
none                   5     0         5   0% /run/lock
none                1975     0      1975   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda4          40317   177     38092   1% /data
/dev/sda1             89    50        34  60% /boot
```

The /dev/sda3 is the home.
The /dev/sda4 is the /data

How to increase the size of sda3 and reduce sda4 ?

Thanks

Comment: /dev/sda3 is the home? Or the system - since it is mounted on / ?

Comment: Yes, it is the home !

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `resize2fs` like this:

```
 resize2fs /dev/sda3 6000M
```

Do note that you can use `resize2fs` to increase and decrease the size of sda.

Comment: Here is the command :  'sudo resize2fs /dev/sda3 6000M', that does not work :/

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, you need to boot off another partition, or even better off another medium. This is because you cannot resize a partition while the partition is mounted.

A LiveCD is ideal for these purposes.

You will need to check the filesystem on the partitions you will be resizing, and then resize them, otherwise the resize will refuse to proceed. You can do this from the command line with e2fsck and resize2fs. On the other hand, a graphical tool may be helpful. I often use gparted, with good results on ext4 partitions. The bar display helps give you a better sense of precisely where the existing partitions are on your disk, and how much leeway you have on either side.

HTH.

Comment: The problem is that I'm on a dedicated server.